# Video url cannot be found when scraping page

Tags: python, html, selenium, video, web-scraping

I want to download the video from the following page:

https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/protest-the-hero-new-album--3#/

Using Firebug, I can see the url of the video,

```
<video src="https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/1449/2/57246728/138634997.mp4?expires=1457996449&amp;token=089e435c20e7781d36fce" preload="metadata">
</video>
```

However, I tried to scape the page using Python, this sentence is lost and I could not get the url. I also tried Selenium, but the same problem remained. How could I access the video url with my scraper?

Also, it seems that the video url does not work. How could I get the url from which I can download the video?

Comment: That markup is not in the source code of the page, it's added by a script after the page has loaded. That's why you can't scrape it. I doubt it's anything malicious; probably more with providing the video in a format the user's browser can actually play. You'll need to dig into the page a lot more to figure out how to get the video URL.

Comment: Thanks! So what I see from Firebug is not the source of the page? Could I  always find the video url from the html?

Comment: It's the markup of the page as it's displayed by the browser (including any markup added by scripts), not as it's served from the Web host. With Selenium you might be able to dig it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

The trick is that *the desired `video` tag is inside the `iframe`* - you would need to switch into it's context and then search for the `video` element. Then, use [`get_attribute()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) to get the `src` attribute value. Complete working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()  # or webdriver.Firefox(), or webdriver.PhantomJS() or etc.
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.get('https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/protest-the-hero-new-album--3#/')

# waiting for the frame to become present
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#vimeoPlayer")))
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)

# get video url
url = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("video").get_attribute("src")
print(url)

browser.close()
```

Prints:

```
https://09-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/1449/2/57246728/138634997.mp4?expires=1457998452&token=0c54810bc365a94ea8486
```